# How to get target location when using TrackerObjectQuad in Boofcv

Tags: java, boofcv

I am using a tracker i.e
`TrackerObjectQuad tracker = FactoryTrackerObjectQuad.circulant(null, GrayU8.class);` and also `TrackerObjectQuadPanel gui = new TrackerObjectQuadPanel(null);` as gui for displaying results. I am setting the target as `gui.setTarget(location, true);`.

How can I get the target location?

One option was to get a low level tracker as [here](http://boofcv.org/javadoc/boofcv/abst/tracker/TrackerObjectQuad.html#getLowLevelTracker--). I don't know how to use it.

Please tell me if there is any other option?

Comment: that gives you a box for the target's location. Do you just want a point?

Comment: No, I want the quadrilateral to detect the location of the target.

Comment: So you want it to automatically detect the target, find its bounding rectangle, then track it? Object trackers can only be used after it has been detected.